# Can't calculate with Array.length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to change the color of the box by time.
I want to calculate the next color with a counter, and modulo it with number of colors I have.
With a normal Number this works fine, but if i use Array.lenght I get NaN as result.

```js
box = document.getElementById("box");
k = 0;
colors = ["purple", "green", "red", "orange", "yellow", "blue"];

setInterval(function() {
  console.log(colors.length); // shows 6
  box.style.backgroundColor = colors[k];
  k++;
  k = k % colors.lenght;
  // k %= 6; works fine.
  console.log(k); // shows NaN
}, 1000);
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Thx for your help.

Comment: `length` != `lenght`.

Comment: `lenght` is supposed to be `length`

Comment: Typo in `k = k % colors.lenght;` » `k = k % colors.length;`

Comment: You just made a Type, it should be `length` not `lenght`, hope you got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have spelling mistake in your code.`k = k % colors.lenght;` should be  `k = k % colors.length;`

Answer (score 1):

A long shot, but could it just be a spelling mistake?
`k = k % colors.lenght;`
should be:
`k = k % colors.length;`

...happens to me all the time

Comment: That's why IDEs do make sense ;)

Comment: Too true, though I'll occasionally hack something in RPi or someone else's system and typically basic, no-frills vim or a text editor is the first place I start.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20855110)

Comment: @MikeBoutin, you've just clicked a wrong button during a review. This *does* answer the question. Most probably you saw a question mark while clicking through the reviews and reacted as if it were a question posted as an answer. To avoid this, I recommend to **actually read** the question and the answer.

Comment: @AlexShesterov it's the same answer than the one accepted and it finishes with `...happens to me all the time`

Comment: @MikeBoutin, yes, but if you hover over the "answered XX hours ago", you can see that this one was posted at 19:11:28 UTC - 3 minutes earlier than the accepted one. For The Great Justice...

Answer (score 0):

You have `colors.lenght` not `colors.length`.